# "There they buried Yitzchak" — not "my father"?

Tags: names, avot-patriarch-fathers, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, vayechi

"What is awe" of a parent? asks *Shulchan Aruch Yore Dea* 240:2. It includes, *SA* answers, that one

> shall not call [his parent] by [the latter's] name, neither during [the parent]'s life, nor in his death. Rather, he says "my father, my master".

Allow me to quote the *Pische S'shuva* :2, not to focus on his content, but, rather, merely as an example of how far this prohibition goes, how strict it is:

> It seems to me that if others ask of him, "Whose son are you?", telling them "I am the son of *Reb* So-and-so" is permitted. Evidence of this [ruling] is from what the *Maharshal* wrote (in paraphrase):
>
> > That the *Rosh* referred to his teacher the *Maharam* of Rothenburg by name is all right, as he had multiple teachers and needed to clarify, but by one's father it's forbidden, as he has but one father [so can always say simply "my father"]. The fact that the *Tur* mentioned his father [by name] is okay, as he mentioned him in a respectful manner "the *Rosh*" which [besides being an acronym of his name] means "head", i.e. of all Jews.
>
> Thus, if people don't know his father so he must mention him [by name], it's also okay.

(As always, for practical *halacha*, consult your rabbi.)

The very last thing *Yaakov* is recorded in *Chumash* as saying was (*Vaychi* 49:29–33):

> I am [dying]. Bury me near my fathers in the cave in the field... that *Avraham* bought... as a burial plot. There they buried *Avraham* and *Sara* his wife; there they buried *Yitzchak* and *Rivka* his wife; and there I buried *Lea*....

Why did he refer to his parents and grandparents by their names, not even adorned with any honorifics?

(One can, as always, answer that, living before *matan Tora*, *Yaakov* was not obligated in any *mitzva* and therefore was not obligated in the *mitzva* of awe for parents. I am seeking meatier answers.)

Comment: The Aruch haShulchan 240:2 asks the same question from other sources and answers that you can use their name, but also need to use the word abba, as in v'shem avosai Avraham v'Yitzchak, though that doesn't work here, unless we say the Torah is paraphrasing, although it's a strange omission.  (AhS: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14244&st=&pgnum=195)

Comment: @YDK: perhaps you meant [240:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14244&pgnum=197)? In any case, maybe since he mentioned "avosai" earlier in his instructions (קברו אותי אל אבותי), then by the same token he's then allowed to mention them by name (i.e., the honorific doesn't have to directly precede the name), although I don't know whether that's correct.

Comment: @msh210, Sorry about that.  It was the 2nd seif on the page in my hardcopy, and misquoted and mis-linked  that as seif 2.  Alex's link is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is discussed by R' Yaakov Tzvi Mecklenburg in [Hak'sav V'hakabbala](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14121&st=&pgnum=206).

Originally, he suggests, as @Alex did in the comments, that it was permitted since Yaakov had already introduced them at his fathers in starting with "קברו אותי אל אבותי".
However, because of other cases where we find this rule violated (namely, Bereshis 50:24 and 25:4), he offers the following explanation:

The reason that one generally may not call his parent by their first name is that a name in itself signifies a person as he was born; only through living his life can he achieve honorary titles. Thus, by calling a father by his first name, one is disrespecting him by implying that he has not achieved anything in his lifetime which deserves an additional dignified title.

When it comes to the *avos*, however, this is not the case. The names of the *avos* are intrinsically honorary. They were the names by which they were called by God and destined for greatness. Thus, there is no greater respect than to be called by these names, and the disrespect involved in referring to a father by his first name does not apply here.

Comment: This answer is very mind-blowing! Thanks for that! I know there's a source that Hashem named Yitzchak, but I can't find it. Not sure, did Hashem name Rivka and Leah? Is the point that Hashem named them, or that Hashem called _to them_ by their name, or simply that they are the Avot? The original point is it's demeaning to be referred to by something you haven't earned, so are we saying all the Avot and Imahot "earned" their name or just that the fact of Hashem calling them/to them is a honour in itself, which diminishes the former dishonour to vanishing point?

Answer (score 2):

I'll add that the *Ben Ish Chai* gave two reasons:

- Everything Yaakov said was said in *ruach hakodesh*, so he was **required** to speak in a very exact way, it wasn't just his own free way of speaking.
- Yaakov did say something like "my great, honored, father, teacher, etc.", but the Torah puts it down eventually as what is needed for future generations, in a shorter manner.

Rabbi Mordechai Eliyahu *ZT"L* went with the second opinion.

Sources:

- http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/4157
- http://din.org.il/2012/01/09/%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%90%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%A6%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%A2%D7%A6%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3/
- http://www.harav.org/Torato/ArticleDetail.asp?ID=264